# Incomplete information (e.g., page number or year) in references. How to avoid sloppy references (e.g., ???? and ,.)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

For some citations, I do not have page number or other information. For example, not all conference papers specify page numbers. When I do not enter these information, the reference shows up sloppy.

For example:

> [3] Penner JE. Eects of soot aerosols from aircraft on cirrus cloud. In: DSVS International Workshop on Aviation. 2008,.

As seen, the reference finishes with `,.` instead of simply `.`

Another example is:

> [5] Smith GP, Golden DM, Frenklach M, Moriarty NW,Eiteneer B, Goldenberg M, et al. GRI-Mech 3.0. http://www.me.berkeley.edu/gri_mech/; ????

As seen, the missing year appears as `????`.

Is there a way to let LaTeX know what parts are missing so it ignores that part. Obviously leaving that section blank does not work. I also cannot change the styling because this is the style for the journal that I am planning to submit my paper.

Comment: Which style do you use? This may be deliberate (some journals insist that full page details are given).

Comment: elsarticle-template-3-num from Elsevier. http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle#bibtex

Comment: Just re-read the guideline for authors and could not find a mention of forcing all details but I guess it may not be explicitly stated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal example, showing your `.bib` entries for the problematic citations. I suspect you may need to alter how you've entered them, but at present I'd be guessing.

Comment: No response from @Emre makes this question impossible to answer as-is. I'll therefore close it.